# Unknown error in explicit conversion: java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm having issues with this code and I'm not sure why, can someone help me, please? I'm trying to refactor my main method and my ide won't allow me to because of this error. the error lies on line 24, I've marked it with a comment. As per request, I've included the error message and the calculate balance method.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tald3.png)

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
final static int Months_In_Year = 12; 
final static int Percent = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int principal = (int) readNumber("Principal: ", 1000, 1_000_000);
    double annualInterest = (double) readNumber("Annual Interest Rate: ", 1, 30);
    byte years = (byte) readNumber("Period(years):  ", 1, 30);

    printMortgage(principal, annualInterest, years);

    System.out.println("PAYMENT SCHEDULE");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    for( short month = 1; month < years * Months_In_Year; month++){
        double balance = calculateBalance(principal, annualInterest, years, month); // error here
        System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(balance));
    }

}

private static void printMortgage(int principal, double annualInterest, byte years) {
    double mortgage = calculateMortgage(principal, annualInterest, years);
    String mortgageCalculated = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(mortgage);
    System.out.println("MORTGAGE");
    System.out.println("---------------------");
    System.out.println("Monthly Payments: " + mortgageCalculated);
}

public static double readNumber(String prompt, double min, double max) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double value;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        value = scanner.nextDouble(); //change to float, don't need as much memory
        if ((value >= min) && (value <= max))
            break;

        System.out.println("Pick value between " + min + " and " + max);
    }
    return value;
}


public static double calculateMortgage(
        int principal,
        double annualInterest,
        byte years) {
    double monthlyInterest = annualInterest / (Percent * Months_In_Year);
    double numberOfPayments = years * Months_In_Year;
    double mortgage = principal
            * (monthlyInterest * Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments)
            / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments));
    return mortgage;
}

public static double calculateBalance (
        int principal,
        double mortgage,
        double annualInterest,
        byte years,
        short numberOfPaymentsMade ){

    double monthlyInterest = annualInterest / (Percent * Months_In_Year);
    double numberOfPayments = years * Months_In_Year;
    double balance =(double) principal *
            (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments)
            / (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - 1));
                    return balance;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error, and have you written a `calculateBalance` method? Where is it? `calculateMortgage` is similarly invisible.

Comment: Please also post the original error message (could also be a screenshot).

Comment: `calculateBalance` takes a `double mortgage` as the second argument. You are not passing anything.

Comment: what part is confusing you? you have a method that needs 5 arguments, you only pass 4

Comment: This has nothing to do with 'explicit conversion'. The error message states the problem perfectly clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In code below

```
public static double calculateBalance (
        int principal,
        double mortgage,
        double annualInterest,
        byte years,
        short numberOfPaymentsMade ){

    double monthlyInterest = annualInterest / (Percent * Months_In_Year);
    double numberOfPayments = years * Months_In_Year;
    double balance =(double) principal *
            (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments)
            / (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - 1));
                    return balance;

    }
}
```

remove double mortgage, as we don't need it. Thus final ans:-

```
public static double calculateBalance (
        int principal,
        double annualInterest,
        byte years,
        short numberOfPaymentsMade ){

    double monthlyInterest = annualInterest / (Percent * Months_In_Year);
    double numberOfPayments = years * Months_In_Year;
    double balance =(double) principal *
            (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments)
            / (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - 1));
                    return balance;

    }
}
```